# forward message from a user to the other users on the server

Tags: c, sockets

I want to forward message from one user to the others with a server between.
I accept the connection by `connfd = accept(tcpfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &len);` i saw some codes on the internet that use the return value of `accept` to identify a different client who connected to the server but when I checked the return value of `accept` for 5 clients, all of them returned 4.
I can send a message to the first client with `send(connfd, *,*,*);` but how to get info from the other client which I can use in `send` function to send them message?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you may using a single variable to store the return value of `accept` that keeps getting overwritten each time you call it.  It's impossible to know for sure however without a [mcve].

Comment: Seems like each time after a connection is accept()ed it is close()d. If the connection fd was alive, it shouldn't have returned the same file descriptor number. You can then use getsockname() on the fd to get the client's IP and port.

Comment: @Semion now it's working! thank you so much